# have an error in my javascript it say the (e) is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

the code I have and the error in the image

```js
import React from 'react';

const Main = () => {
  const joiningCriteria = [
    'People between the ages of 18 and 35 years.',
    'A demonstrated passion for coding and technology.',
    'The time and capacity to commit to a full coding bootcamp. Classes are three times per week in person at one of our learning hubs.',
    'An intermediate level of English comprehension.',
    'The aptitude to succeed in the selection process.',
  ];
  return (
    <section class="bootcamp">
      <ol>
        {joiningCriteria.map(() => (
          <li>{e}</li> /*the error is here it say the (e) is not defined*/
        ))}
      </ol>
    </section>
  );
};
export default Main;
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Did you define `e` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a map to work you have to pass a variable which allows to select each element. Try this

```
const joiningCriteria = [

'People between the ages of 18 and 35 years.',
'A demonstrated passion for coding and technology.',
'The time and capacity to commit to a full coding bootcamp. Classes are three times per week in person at one of our learning hubs.',
'An intermediate level of English comprehension.',
'The aptitude to succeed in the selection process.',
];

return (

  <ol>        
      {joiningCriteria.map((e,index)=> {return <li key={index}>{e}</li>} /*the error is here it say the (e) is not defined*/
    )}
  </ol>
 
</section>
); };
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226136/discussion-on-answer-by-jibin-francis-have-an-error-in-my-javascript-it-say-the).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your e inside the map as an argument.
Your values from the array will then be displayed as list elements.

```
  <ol>        
      {joiningCriteria.map((e)=> (<li>{e}</li>))}
  </ol>
```

Comment: thank you for answering but i already tried that but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

please Add (e) into map
like

From

```
map(()=>
```

to

```
map((e)=>
```

it will work

Thanks

Comment: i tried that but not working i dont know why

Comment: can you please error that occurs in console

Comment: Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'C:\Users\yadba\OneDrive\Desktop\coding-challenge-yad97-main\src'

Comment: thats what the compiler say

Comment: try this one map(e => (

Comment: its the same still not working